# not able to send emails on gmail

Tags: php, email

I am able to send email to other emails are `yahoo`,`hotmail`,`rediff` but not able to send email on `gmail`.

Below is my code

```
<?php
    // the message
    $msg = "test text";

    // send email
    if(mail("myemail@gmail.com","My subject",$msg)){
        echo "dsaf";
    }
?>
```

How can I fix this issue.

Comment: Check the spam folder of your gmail.

Comment: Already checked. Nothing there.

Comment: You are missing headers, also the returned value from `mail()` does not actually say if the mail has been received.

Answer (score 0):

Most mail services will filter out messages send by PHP mail().  [Pear mail](https://pear.php.net/package/Mail), on the other hand, allows for you to actually login to the gmail SMTP server when sending mail.  This mail won't be filtered.  Make sure when doing so that you alter your gmail settings to allow for less secure clients.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code.

```
$to = 'somemail@gmail.com';
$name = "John Doe";
$email = "john.doe@yahoo.com";
$message = "Test Message";

$subject = "Message from ".$name;
$message = $name . " ( ". $email . " ) wrote the following:" . "\n\n" . $message;

$headers = "From:" . $email;
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

Comment: still there is no mail.

Comment: In my case I am receiving emails. Have you changed the `$to` email?

Answer (score 0):

You have to enable SMTP relay service setting https://support.google.com/a/answer/2956491

Also check, 
https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en